# Names of female scholars from Vaidic and Upanishadic times, or "Brahmavadinis"

Tags: vedas, upanishads, women, rishi

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmavadini) provides the names of some of the "**Brahmavadinis" (ब्रह्मवादिनी)** or female scholars of ancient times, who studied topics related to **brahman (ब्रह्म)** and took part in debates and discussions about brahman (ब्रह्म) similar to how men participated.

Example:

> Lopamudra, Ghosha, Sulabha, Maitreyi, Gargi etc.

Apart from the above names, are there any other female "Bhramvadinies"  mentioned in any of the Vedic or Upanishadic literature or scripture?

I would also like to know in brief about their works (literature) and any stories associated with these women, if any are available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Brihad Devata, 2.82-84 [Sanskrit Source](https://archive.org/details/brhaddevataattri01saunuoft) and [English Transliteration Source](https://archive.org/stream/brhaddevataattri01saunuoft/brhaddevataattri01saunuoft_djvu.txt), there are several Brahmavadinis as follows:

> Ghosa Godha Visvavara Apalopanisan Nisat ;
>
> Brahmajaya Juhur nama, Agastyasya svasaditih. [82]
>
> Indrani cendramata ca Sarama Romasorvasi;
>
> Lopamudra ca Nadyas ca Yami nari ca Sasvati .[83]
>
> Srir Laksa Sarparajnl Vak Sraddha Medha ca Daksina;
>
> Ratrl Surya ca Savitrl brahmavadinya Iritah. [84]

- Ghosa: Name of the authoress of [RV 5.39](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-x/suktha-i-to-l/suktha-39) and [RV 5.40](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-x/suktha-i-to-l/suktha-40)
- Godha: Name of the authoress of a Sāman [Source](http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/index.php?contents=lemma&IDWord=124815)
- Visvavara: Name of the authoress of the hymn [RV 5.28](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-v/topic-28)
- Apala: Name of the authoress of the hymn [RV 8.91](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-viii/suktha-lxxxi-to-ciii/topic-91)
- Upanisat
- Nisat
- Juhu Brahmajaya: Name of the authoress of the hymn [RV 10.109](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-x/suktha-ci-to-cxx/suktha-109)
- Agastyasya
- Aditi: Name of the authoress of the hymn [RV 4.18](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-iv/topic-18)
- Indrani: Name of the authoress of the hymn [RV 10.86](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-x/suktha-li-to-c/suktha-86)
- Indramata
- Sarama: Name of the reputed authoress of [RV 10.108](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-x/suktha-ci-to-cxx/suktha-108)
- Romasa: Name of the reputed authoress of [RV 1.126,7](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-i/topic-126)
- Oorvasi
- Lopamudra: Name of the authoress of [RV 1.179](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-i/topic-179)
- Nadya
- Yami
- Sasvati: Name of the authoress of [RV 8.1](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-viii/suktha-i-to-xx/topic-1)
- Sri Lakshaa
- Sarparajni
- Vak
- Sraddha
- Medha
- Daksina: Name of the authoress of [RV 10.107](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-x/suktha-ci-to-cxx/suktha-107)
- Ratri
- Surya Savitri: Name of the authoress of [RV 10.85](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-x/suktha-li-to-c/suktha-85)

Except these, there are some others.

- Vasukrapatni: Name of the authoress of the verse [RV 10.28.1](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-x/suktha-i-to-l/suktha-28)

I have also taken help from [Hindupedia.com](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Women_as_Rishikas_in_the_Vedas) website.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar thanks I am still editing and will add that part too.

Comment: Yes , nice find , i will also do the same ,with sources.:)

Answer (score 4):

As already answered [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33205/), [R. L. Kashyap](http://vedah.com/rlk/) in *[Essentials of Rig Veda](http://vedah.com/product/essentials-of-rig-veda/)* lists about 30 ṛṣhikās (women seers of Rigveda) along with the verse numbers. The author also notes the list is not exhaustive.

```
Appendix

Women Ṛṣhis (ṛṣhikā) in the Rig Veda Samhitā

Aditi                   4.18

Aditirdākshāyaṇī        10.72

Agastyasvasā            10.60.6

Apālā Ātreyī            8.91

Dakshiṇā Prājapatyā     10.107

Godhā                   10.134

Goṣhā Kākshīvatī        10.39, 10.40

Indrāṇī                 10.86, 10.145

Indra-mātaraḥ           10.153

Jaritā Sharṇgā          10.142

Juhūrbrahmajāyā         10.109

Kāshyapī                9.104

Lopāmudrā               1.179

Rātrīrbhāradvājī        10.127

Romashā                 1.126

Suryā Sāvitrī           10.85

Saramā Devashunī        10.108

Sārparājnī              10.189

Sashvatyāṇgīrasī        8.1

Shachī Paulomī          10.159

Shradhdā Kāmāyānī       10.151

Sikatā Nivāvarī         9.86

Sudītīrangirasā         8.71

Tvaṣhṭa Garbhakartā     10.184

Urvashī                 10.95

Vāgambhṛṇī              10.125

Vasukrapatnī            10.28

Vishvavārā Ātreyī       5.28

Yamī Vaivasvatī         10.10

Yamī                    10.154

(The list is not exhaustive)
```

Comment: You shouldn't post same answer multiple times..

Comment: Yeah, normally I don't but I didn't think both questions were exact duplicates. Do you have a link to any Meta.SE post that says we shouldn't? @TheDestroyer

Answer (score -1):

None. There are no women who authored the Veda. For example:

Indrani = Goddess

Yami = Goddess

Aditi = Goddess

Urvashi = Apsara

The women that do seem to appear are just interlocutors. Women have some serious problems that were put in them since Brahma created them. This is confirmed everywhere like:

> Ever since the five elements, the world, the men and women were created by Brahmā, O Nārada, the **defect lies in women always.** [(Shiva Purana, Uma Samhita, 24.35)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226584.html)

> "Whence the five great elements have sprung into existence, whence the Creator Brahma hath ordained the universe, and whence, indeed, men have sprung, verily from the same eternal source have women sprung into existence. At that time, again, O Narada, **when women were created, these faults that I have enumerated were planted in them!**'"
> [(Mahabharata, Anushasana Parva XXXVIII)](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b003.htm)

**Such "people" cannot author sacred scriptures.** In fact, in most of the cases women were not supposed to learn Vedas or take Sanyasa. It is possible, but not recommended at all nor the general trend. So almost forget about anything higher than that.

Comment: What about Vagambhirini (daughter of sage Ambrunar), Lopamudra, ....

Comment: **1)** According to pre-modern commentaries supreme goddess herself is possessing and creating hymn through Vak. So Vak is just a medium and **the hymn is created by supreme Goddess herself. 2)** In sexual/Rati hymn Lopamudra created from animal parts is just an interlocutor calling her husband in 2 sentences!

Comment: Another traditional view is that **Vak, Shraddha, Dakshina, Ratri are ritual entities personified** - that is, abstact ideas. The list is literally calling Surya Savitri, Sarama and goddesses or celestial beings as "rishikas" I don't know why such posts are given upvotes and nobody points out the problem @Tezz

Comment: @R Kaushik by the same logic, many or most of the sages weren't 'men' either since they were created by BrahmA as Saptarishis unlike men who are descendants of Manu; the question wasn't whether the Rishika was a mAnavi or divya stree

Comment: @RishitaGhosh No because Vishwamitra was saptrishi who became Brahmin later (from Kshatriya family) and other Saptrishis were human, not Gods. Jabala, Ailusha and other Vedic authors were mostly men. The question specifically uses the word "women" PLEASE READ IT AGAIN