# List of female Vedic seers (rishkAs)

Tags: vedas, mantras, women, rishi, samhita

Can someone please post the list of female seers to whom the Vedic Samhita mantras were revealed?

Like a list of seer and sukta and mantra with mandala or chapter number would be highly appreciated

Comment: Please check [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15338/4038)

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani i think some names are not clear

Comment: Please make sure that the list is correct as i m going to use it as a reference

Comment: I have cited some reliable sources in that, you may suggest if anything wrong with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[R. L. Kashyap](http://vedah.com/rlk/) in *[Essentials of Rig Veda](http://vedah.com/product/essentials-of-rig-veda/)* lists about 30 ṛṣhikās along with the verse numbers. The author notes the list is not exhaustive.

```
Appendix

Women Ṛṣhis (ṛṣhikā) in the Rig Veda Samhitā

Aditi                   4.18

Aditirdākshāyaṇī        10.72

Agastyasvasā            10.60.6

Apālā Ātreyī            8.91

Dakshiṇā Prājapatyā     10.107

Godhā                   10.134

Goṣhā Kākshīvatī        10.39, 10.40

Indrāṇī                 10.86, 10.145

Indra-mātaraḥ           10.153

Jaritā Sharṇgā          10.142

Juhūrbrahmajāyā         10.109

Kāshyapī                9.104

Lopāmudrā               1.179

Rātrīrbhāradvājī        10.127

Romashā                 1.126

Suryā Sāvitrī           10.85

Saramā Devashunī        10.108

Sārparājnī              10.189

Sashvatyāṇgīrasī        8.1

Shachī Paulomī          10.159

Shradhdā Kāmāyānī       10.151

Sikatā Nivāvarī         9.86

Sudītīrangirasā         8.71

Tvaṣhṭa Garbhakartā     10.184

Urvashī                 10.95

Vāgambhṛṇī              10.125

Vasukrapatnī            10.28

Vishvavārā Ātreyī       5.28

Yamī Vaivasvatī         10.10

Yamī                    10.154

(The list is not exhaustive)
```

Comment: Oh I was about to post the answer but u posted before .. So u also have bought this book?

Comment: exshaustive llist would be  appreciated...

Comment: Yeah, it would be good to have a list of all female seers across all 4 Vedas. But I'm not sure if anyone has compiled such a list. R. L. Kashyap doesn't discuss ṛṣhikās at all in his summaries/translations of the other 3 Vedas. @RakeshJoshi