# Women and Hinduism

Tags: scripture, vedas, dharma-shastras, women, smriti

It's traditionally believed that some hymns of Vedas have been authored by women. How does one reconcile this with the fact that women are not allowed to recite vedas? (Are those author women considered to be exception?)

Comment: Please give specific examples and references of "some hymns".

Comment: Ambarini suktha

Comment: Not authored, they were Rishikas (female Rishis) who had heard those mantras of Vedas. See this for example: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/33198/4732

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please have a look at this post. It talks of women being sanctioned Yajnopavita in at least 1 of the 18 main Smritis - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6667/rules-for-wearing-yagyopavit-by-women-yes-it-is-possible. Also some other Smritis do mention women and their husbands doing Agnihotra together or at least in the absence of the husband. So chanting the Vedas is very much allowed.

Answer (score 2):

From Harita Dharma sutra [21,23](https://archive.org/details/yajnavalkyasmrit00yj/page/102/mode/2up?view=theater)

> Women belong to two classes. Brahmavadinis and Sadyovadhus. Among these two, there is ordained for Brahmavadinis the sacrament of investiture with sacred thread, the fire sacrifice, the study of the Vcdas in her own house and to beg alms. For Sadyovadhus, the rule is that when their marriageable time approaches, the mere formality of investiture with sacred thread should be done, and then they should be married away.